# How to exclude header row using Google Query and importrange

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, importrange

I have a Google Query that is designed to import data from a single column in 6 separate Google Sheets. I also need to exclude the Header row in the source spreadsheet. My query is constructed as follows:

`=query({importrange("Key","Range");importrange("Key","Range");......)},"Select * where Col1 <> ''",0)`

What is happening is all the data from each source sheet is coming in but at each block of data the column header is also shown. Example below:

```
Header
data
data
data
Header
data
data
data
Header
data
data
```

The `,0)` at the end is my attempt to exclude the header row. It works when I use the following query with a date column:

`... where Col1 is not null",0)`

Comment: The Example in the text above should have each word on a new row and not strung across the page as shown...

Comment: Can't you adjust the range so that it starts below the header row and only import the header row from the first importange (assuming headers are the same in all sheets)?  I believe something like this should work: {importrange("Key","A1:Z");importrange("Key","A2:Z");......

Comment: That was how I originally constructed the query. However, and perhaps I should have included this bit of information before, the source sheets are fed by Jotform responses and if I clear out the data, then somehow the data range shifts down to what was the last row - i.e. importrange("Key","A2:A1000"); becomes importrange("Key","A5:A1000");... Very frustrating as I cannot see how this is happening. That was the reason I went to include the entire row and somehow exclude the header row in the import.

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("Key", "Sheet1!A1:Z");
        IMPORTRANGE("Key", "Sheet1!A1:Z");......}, "where Col1 is not null", 0)
```

do this:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("Key", "Sheet1!A2:Z");
        IMPORTRANGE("Key", "Sheet1!A2:Z");......}, "where Col1 is not null", 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

={QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("Key", "Sheet1!A2:Z"), "Select Col1 where Col1 is not null **offset 1**");
 QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("Key", "Sheet1!A2:Z"), "Select Col1 where Col1 is not null **offset 1**")}